# use recursion to refactor

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, functional-programming

I'm writing a function to access JSON (in localStorage) with a dot notation. The `get()` function below works, but is verbose (and limited)

I'm sure there's a better way of refactoring this with recursion. Any ideas?

```
get(str) {

  var keys = str.split('.')
  var parent = JSON.parse({"first":{"second":{"third":{"something":"here"}}}})

  if ( keys.length === 1 ) return parent
  if ( keys.length === 2 ) return parent[keys[1]]
  if ( keys.length === 3 ) return parent[keys[1]][keys[2]]
  if ( keys.length === 4 ) return parent[keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]]

}

get('first')
get('first.second')
get('first.second.third')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lodash.get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get) ([documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get)) which works just fine.

```
const get = require('lodash.get');

get('first')
get('first.second')
get('first.second.third')
```